# Smartgwt select treenode from code

Tags: tree, smartgwt, treegrid

I have a `TreeGrid` in which I have a `Tree`:

```
Tree nodesTree = new Tree();
TreeGrid navTreeGrid = new TreeGrid(); 
navTreeGrid.setData(nodesTree);
```

and I want everytime I'm adding a node to the tree to get focus on it.

More general, how can I from code to select a `TreeNode` in a `Tree`?

I know it is `navTreeGrid.getSelectedRecord()` method but is not what I want.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the [selectRecord methods](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/grid/ListGrid.html#selectRecord%28int%29).

```
grid.selectRecord(record);
```

Comment: I saw that you know a lot of things related to smartgwt, therefore, with all my repect, I please you look on another issue of mine from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967266/tree-dragdrop-nodes-refresh Thank you so much.